# How can I contain an anchor tag inside my button tag at 100% width and height

Tags: html, css

I started doing a website and I have a problem.
I started making my navigation bar, here's the code:

```
<div class="navGrid">
            <div class="first">ZENZZEX </div>
            <div class="span-col-4 second">
              <a href=""> <button>Services</button></a>     
              <a href="#"><button>About us</button></a>
              <a href="#"><button>Contact us</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="third"><a href="#"><button>Get Started</button></a></div>
          </div>
```

and the problem is that this `<a>` tag is taking space outside my button area. Here's a full code on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/MareGraphics/pen/GwqpOy

What I want is to contain A tag to fit 100% inside my button, not outside od it.
Thank You

Comment: Why do you want to use a `<button>` and a `<a>` tag at once? If you want to create button like visual, add CSS to the `<a>` tag...

Comment: Can I style it the same way as I could do with a button?

Comment: yes you can style it like a button

Comment: why can't you use like this? `<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">get Started Button</a>`

Comment: I can't add HEIGHT attribute to A tag, it just doesn.t work

Comment: I integrated Bootstrap and made a button using that, thanks.

Comment: **You cannot have a button inside a link, or vice versa. That is invalid HTML.** *Permitted content:  Transparent, containing either flow content (**excluding interactive content**) or phrasing content.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot adjust the `height` and `width` of your `<a>` is because anchor elements are `inline-elements`.

> An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.

If you want to adjust the height and width you would need to specify another `display` property, e.g.

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

For what it's worth, it's better to omit the button inside the anchor tag, just style the anchor tag as your button to make it act like a button.

e.g. if you are using bootstrap, you can do

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Get Started</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your buttons from navgrid div and change the CSS like this

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.span-col-4 {
  grid-column: span 4 / auto;
}

.navGrid .first {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: .5s;
}

.navGrid .first:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.31em;
}

.navGrid {
  height: 40px
}

.navGrid .second {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .5s;
}

.navGrid .second a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navGrid .second a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navGrid .second:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navGrid .third {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 26, 255);
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .5s;
  color: white;
}

.navGrid .third a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.navGrid .third:hover {
  background-color: rgb(3, 25, 219);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navGrid .third {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navGrid">
  <div class="first">ZENZZEX </div>
  <div class="span-col-4 second">
    <a href=""> Services</a>
    <a href="#">About us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="third"><a href="#">Get Started</a></div>
</div>
```

I think this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<a style="padding:50px;background-color:gray;width100%;line-height:70px;" class="btn btn-info">Buttons</a>
```